# Sorting list of lists by particular index of inner lists

Tags: sorting, netlogo

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
[["Local 7" 1 "say" "Say: Inspect Fences"] ["Local 7" 1 "do" "Do: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 1 "say" "Say: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 1 "do" "Do: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 2 "say" "Say: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 2 "do" "Do: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 7" 2 "say" "Say: Inspect Fences"] ["Local 7" 2 "do" "Do: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 3 "say" "Say: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 6" 3 "do" "Do: Shepherd Cows"] ["Local 7" 3 "say" "Say: Inspect Fences"] ["Local 7" 3 "do" "Do: Inspect Fences"]]
```

I'd like to sort the list by `item 1`. (I know it already is in the copy/pasted version, but it might not always be.)

`sort` just returns an empty list (I'm not even sure why, but I guess that's a separate question), and `sort-by` doesn't seem to work because it needs a reporter that resolves to a boolean.

Is there a clever way to do this? Or would I need to first get a list of the values I want to sort by, then sort that, and then iterate over that list, creating a new list of the values in the original list in which the respective item value matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Updated with NetLogo 6 syntax

You can convert this into a `sort-by` pretty easily:

```
to-report sort-with [ key lst ]
  report sort-by [ [a b] -> (runresult key a) < (runresult key b) ] lst
end
```

Then you use it like so:

```
sort-with [ l -> item 1 l ] my-list
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you Seth

Comment: Still very helpful, but I think for Netlogo >6 the `task` syntax doesn't work anymore and we need `sort-with [a -> item 1 a] my-list` and `to-report sort-with [ key lst ]
  report sort-by [[?1 ?2] -> (runresult key ?1) < (runresult key ?2)] lst
end` ?

Comment: Thanks nehalem! Updated.