# Sort nested list

Tags: netlogo

I found this code to sort nested list.

```
  to-report test 
  let z [[2 3] [1 9] [3 1] ] 
  report sort-by [(first ?1) < (first ?2)] z 
  end
```

What is first ?1 and first ?2 in this formula. It says that they are not defined as variables.

Comment: Similar solution but again the ?1 and ?2 is used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545569/sorting-list-of-lists-by-particular-index-of-inner-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps using NetLogo v6.0?  Your code works in v5.3.1, but v6.0 uses anonymous reporters.  It would look like:

```
to-report test 
  let z [[2 3] [1 9] [3 1] ] 
  report sort-by [[list1 list2] -> first list1 < first list2] z 
end
```

Charles

Comment: Hello,The problem was netlogo version. Thank you for that but this only sorts first two elements but I would like to sort all the lists in nested list.

Comment: This does that.  It sorts all the sublists in the list of lists. `z`, by their respective first elements.  E.g., if `let z [[2 3] [1 9] [3 1] [0 100] `, the sort will put [0 100] at the beginning of the sorted lists of lists.  Your initial code suggested that you were sorting the sublists by their first elements.  Is that what you wanted? Think of `list1` and `list2` as `?1` and `?2` in your original code.

Comment: You are right it sorts the full list. I had been coding for too long and my brain didn't process the last and first. Changing the item id (first/last) can change the element after what the sorting is done. The code works well. Thank you